# Агент для дискорда

Tags: python, discord, useragent

Ку, Хочу спросить у вас , может кто знает есть ли либа для дискорда которая позволит управлять аком важно акком а не ботом , в идеале что-то типа telethon'a но для дискорда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, юзерботы дискордом запрещены, соответственно вы получите бан очень скоро. Но если вы решитесь на это, то вот вам код авторизации:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in")

client.run("TOKEN", bot=False)
```

[Библиотека](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/) [Документация](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/)